# how to use plot with pre-made parameters set?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to call `plot` with pre-defined parameters.
For example:

```
Params = {'MarkerSize',3,'MarkerFaceColor',[1 0 0.3]}
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),Params)
```

Obviously this is not working, but you get the idea. 
The purpose of doing so is to generate a function that can plot data (for code reuse purpose), except small modifications.
I would like to put in the Params variable only the name-value pairs which are different from the default, and be able to put variable number of pairs.

For example, one time I only put color:

```
Params = {'Color',[1 0.2 0.3]}
```

the other time I put both marker and line width:

```
Params = {'Marker','o','LineWidth',4}
```

Comment: It seems to be working, you should have written that as an answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Moved the comment to an answer since I wasn't sure that was all you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand the cell array of name-value pairs into a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?refresh=true):

```
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2),Params{:});
```